# Prove that electric current in any arbitrary cross section is the same

Tags: electric-circuits, conservation-laws, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

Consider a conductor with variable cross sections there is an electric current in it. Now  prove that electric current in any arbitrary cross section is the same.

Comment: If current is not the same in all parts of a circuit loop, there would be an accumulation of charges in the loop.

Comment: @Aniansh Suppose no loop. then How then?

Comment: No Loop=No Current

Comment: This result is not universally true. You have to restrict the discussion to DC steady state currents, or to small circuits ("lumped" circuits) with no capacitive parasitics. If you think about why you need these assumptions, you'll have most of your answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree @ThePhoton , The No Loop=No Current only applies to steady state DC currents

Answer (score 0):

Current is a flow of charges. They all repel each other. Were there a point with no charges, then they would not be repelled from this point. Then they would move towards this point right away. Only when equilibrium is reached will they not move anywhere anymore.

This is a rough but useful way due to its simplicity to think about this.

How much a charge is repelled from/attracted towards some point is what we call **potential**. A **potential difference** (called **voltage**) between any two points thus corresponds to a net, unbalanced repulsion/attraction from one to the other. Of the above explained reason the potential at all points on a perfect conductor is constant (so the difference/voltage is zero, meaning no net repulsion/attraction anywhere).